# preventing onclick page jumps

Tags: javascript

what is the best way to stop my onclick links from causing the page to jump to the top.

```
<a name="point1">
<a href="#point1" onclick="blahblah">

<a href="javascript:" onclick="blahblah">

<a href="javascript:null;" onclick="blahblah">
```

Or something else?

Comment: I know this is not exactly what you are asking for but you could just not use 'onclick'.
SAMPLE: <a href="javascript: fooBar()">FOO</a>

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I always use

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="blahblah">
```

Comment: Works for me! `Return false;` wasn't working for some reason, but this does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Works perfectly! Just came here to find this out

Comment: imo this isn't HTML5 friendly

Comment: Why not @andrei Just curious.

Comment: @LucasHealy sorry no clue what I had in mind when I said it, comment is almost 5y old. The answer is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Returning false in 'onclick' prevents page jump

```
<a href="#" onclick="someFunction(); return false;">blah</a>
```

Comment: Trying that now with this: onClick="submitComment('+[id]+'); this.onclick=null; return false; but it doesn't work.

Comment: Strange. Returning false should prevent the default link action. Does it work if you try only onclick='return false;'?

Comment: Try changing onClick to onclick. Depending on the MIME type, onClick and onclick can be interpreted as two different attributes.

Comment: if you're doing onClick="submitComment('+[id]+'); this.onclick=null; return false; then it's clear why return false is failing - you are setting the onclick attribute to null, I believe that will immediately stop the execution. I think. Have not tested it though.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="func(); return false;">link</a>
```

Notice that the `onclick` parameter returns `false`.  Returning false cancels the default browser behavior.  In the case of an anchor tag, the default browser behavior is to jump to  the `#` anchor (aka the top of the page).

With this same trick you can also make image un-draggable and ensure that links don't steal the user's focus:

```
<img src="coolios.jpg" onmousedown="return false" /> <!-- un-draggable image -->
<a href="stuff.html" onmousedown="return false">link that doesn't steal focus</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do the trick?

```
<a href="javascript: return false;" onclick="blahblah">
```